# How to return data from activity2 to activity1 if I don't know when activity2 will end?

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

So I have activity 1, which is a main menu activity. Then I have activity 2 which is a store page. The store activity starts with the current user balance. When the user is in the store, he can purchase several things.

I want to send the updated balance back to the main menu activity after the user purchased things. I am using StartActivityForResult but the issue is that I don't know when activity 2 (the store) will end. I don't use a 'finish' button or anything that takes the user back to the main menu. The user just goes back to the main menu by clicking the back button on his phone.

How would I tackle this problem and send back the updated balance to activity 1?

Thank you in advance,

Alexander

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this and you can use any.

1) You can `override` the `onBackPress` method of Activity2 to detect when the user is pressing the back button and set your result there.

2) You can fetch the updated balance from your database when your Activity1's `onStart` method get called. (Or you can use live-data/Data binding for single source of truth)

3) You can use a singleton class to maintain the current balance. Update it in Activity2 and fetch it in Activity1.

Comment: setting the result in `onDestroy()` is too late. `onActivityResult()` will already have been called on `Activity1`. You also don't need a singleton class. You could use just a `public static` variable defined in any class.

Answer (score 1):

`Activity1` should launch `Activity2` using `startActivityForResult()`.

Every time the user does something in `Activity2`, call `setResult()` with an `Intent` containing the current balance in an "extra".

When the user presses the BACK button, `onActivityResult()` will be called in `Activity1` with the last `Intent` that you passed to `setResult()`. You can then extract the current balance from the "extra" in the `Intent.

You don't need to override anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

you can call second activity like this:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

and then in your first activity waiting for result in this way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```